# Problem in my gherkin feature file, scenarious are not working

Tags: selenium, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I'm writing a test consisting of 3 scenarios in total for amazon's website. First, the system is logged in and the test is finished, then the second scenario is run by searching the product in the product search section. However, I used the Background keyword because there is a login requirement for the 2nd scenario to happen. Then, in my 3rd scenario, I run the test by adding products to the cart and deleting them, and for the 3rd scenario to happen, the prerequisites for login and search products must be fulfilled. Therefore, I added a Feature keyword to each scenario, but when I run the code, I did not encounter anything in the console.

Here is my Amazon.feature file

```
Feature: Login Process

  Scenario: Successive Login
    Given User is on homepage
    When Click accept cookies
    When User click login button
    When User click EmailBlank
    And Enter e-mail address
    And User press continue button
    When User click PasswordBlank
    And Enter password
    And Click SignIn button



Feature: Searching and Finding Product after successive login
     #belongs to login
  Background:
    Given User is on homepage
    When Click accept cookies
    When User click login button
    When User click EmailBlank
    And Enter e-mail address
    And User press continue button
    When User click PasswordBlank
    And Enter password
    And Click SignIn button
      #belongs to login

  Scenario: Finding the product from the website
    When Click the search button
    When Write product name
    When Click search button
    When Filter for Shipped by Amazon
    When Filter for Apple



Feature: Adding and Deleting the product from the cart after the successive login and finding the product
      #belongs to login
  Background:
    Given User is on homepage
    When Click accept cookies
    When User click login button
    When User click EmailBlank
    And Enter e-mail address
    And User press continue button
    When User click PasswordBlank
    And Enter password
    And Click SignIn button
     #belongs to login

  #belongs to search and find the product
  Background:
    When Click the search button
    When Write product name
    When Click search button
    When Filter for Shipped by Amazon
    When Filter for Apple
  #belongs to search and find the product

  Scenario: Adding and deleting product to cart
    When Click the first product
    When Add to Cart
    And Close the Cart
    And Click the Cart
    When Check at cart page
    When Delete the product
```

Most probably, the problem is coming from that there should be no Feature: more than one in a single file. What should I do to solve the problem while all conditions are met.

Comment: it is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75294458/how-to-make-background-keyword-as-a-runner-scenario-in-cucumber/75294585

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Background keyword as a runner scenario in cucumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75294458/how-to-make-background-keyword-as-a-runner-scenario-in-cucumber)

Comment: No not really, none of them solved it, I edit the code but it does not work still. This is not duplicate.